# Biblatex ignores mincitenames and maxcitenames in some cases

Tags: biblatex

I have this minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear-comp,maxcitenames=3,mincitenames=1]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
 
 \autocite{Elhmaidi1993,Babiano1994}
 
 %\autocite{Babiano2007}
\end{document}
```

with `test.bib` contents at the end of the post. The MWE generates:
[image]
following to the letter the `biblatex` settings. However, if I remove the commented line, I get:
[image]
which seems to be disobedient of the options suddenly. I thought thought that this could be some issue with ambiguity of the author names, but if you check the `bib` file, they are identical. So I have no idea, what this is caused by, if the years were the same, I would understand but those years are different.

```
@article{Babiano1994,
  title = {Chaotic Advection in Point Vortex Models and Two‐dimensional Turbulence},
  author = {Babiano, Armando and Boffetta, Guido and Provenzale, Antonello and Vulpiani, Angelo},
  date = {1994-07-01},
  journaltitle = {Physics of Fluids},
  shortjournal = {Physics of Fluids},
  volume = {6},
  number = {7},
  pages = {2465--2474},
  issn = {1070-6631},
  doi = {10.1063/1.868194},
  url = {https://doi.org/10.1063/1.868194},
  urldate = {2024-03-12}
}

@article{Babiano2007,
  title = {Coherent Vortices and Tracer Cascades in Two-Dimensional Turbulence},
  author = {Babiano, Armando and Provenzale, Antonello},
  date = {2007-03},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
  volume = {574},
  pages = {429--448},
  issn = {1469-7645, 0022-1120},
  doi = {10.1017/S0022112006004265},
  url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/coherent-vortices-and-tracer-cascades-in-twodimensional-turbulence/649C7D02E66BD2C0D14323A15E9C8D2F},
  urldate = {2024-03-12},
  langid = {english}
}


@article{Elhmaidi1993,
  title = {Elementary Topology of Two-Dimensional Turbulence from a {{Lagrangian}} Viewpoint and Single-Particle Dispersion},
  author = {Elhmaïdi, Dalila and Provenzale, Antonello and Babiano, Armando},
  date = {1993-12},
  journaltitle = {Journal of Fluid Mechanics},
  volume = {257},
  pages = {533--558},
  issn = {1469-7645, 0022-1120},
  doi = {10.1017/S0022112093003192},
  url = {https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-fluid-mechanics/article/elementary-topology-of-twodimensional-turbulence-from-a-lagrangian-viewpoint-and-singleparticle-dispersion/FBC297707D47D8F0A4D780BB8172CA1E},
  urldate = {2024-03-12},
  langid = {english}
}
```

Comment: @Marijn Yes, thank you!